# Cisco VPN connection issue on windows 8

Tags: vpn

I am facing issue with cisco vpn client on windows 8. VPN connects good but i cannot access network resources like file server etc. In win7 there is no issue vpn connecs fine and i can access all the network resources. 
my OS is  Win8 Pro 64 bit.
please anybody help.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Symantec Endpoint protection which didn't work. What solved the issue for me was installing [Shrewsoft VPN](https://www.shrew.net/download/vpn). After I installed it, I was able to ping the local network on go online which I wasn't able to do with the Cisco VPN even though it said I was connected.